# Is it possible to recursively populate missing shared objects when calling dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM)?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, posix, dynamic-linking

When a shared library is opened with `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM)`, there are no existing shared libraries in the new namespace so many libraries will crash or at least give unresolved symbols.

Is it possible to load a .so with `LM_ID_NEWLM` and pull in all of the .so's that were already linked to the running application?

I could walk `/proc/$$/maps` and pull them in first, but it seems like that should be unnecessary.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API to copy shared libraries to new namespace from default one. You can either use `/proc/self/maps` as you suggested or better yet, use [dl_iterate_phdr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr) (`/proc` may not always be mounted).

As a side note, if your library fails to load due to unresolved symbols it means that it should be fixed to include its dependencies.

Comment: Will loading all the libs with RTLD_LAZY before trying to dlsym() a symbol avoid unresolved symbol issues?

Comment: yugr: As it turns out, dlmopen() namespaces do not support RTLD_GLOBAL because of this bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18684 .  The consequence of this is that loading all the libraries I need into the new namespace using something like dl_iterate_phdr() won't work after all---besides, dlmopen() should do that job. The problem I was having was actually this bug, not that libraries were missing.